# How do I create a universal relationships table between distinct resources like books, video, photos in DDD architecture?

Tags: node.js, domain-driven-design, relationship

I'm wondering how to approach making something like a denormalized universal relationships table within a Domain Design project (using NodeJS, NestJS).  The relationships, similar to a 'like' in social media that can be applied to different item types, would potentially cross bounded contexts, but would not need to have knowledge of the context's domain and internal logic.

In database terms, this is the concept, though not generally good practice:

```
Table: Universal_Relationships

Rel_ID  |   Res_A_ID    |   Res_A_Type  |   Res_B_ID    |   Res_B_Type

12              23              2               344             6


Table: Resource_Types

Type_ID |   Type_Name

2           Map_Location
6           Research_Reference
8           Photo
10          Artwork
11          Video
12          Note
[…]

Table: Map_Locations

Place_ID    |   Marker_Title    |   Coord_X (or Lat)    |   Coord_Y (or Long)   |   Description

    2           Eugene                  44.064319           -123.0825664                City

Table: Research_Reference

Ref_ID  |   Title           |   Publisher       |   Abstract

    6       Tourist Guide       Collins             Guide to ...
```

Any help much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest modeling a relationship as an aggregate (different kinds of relationships might be different aggregates or you might just have **Relationship** be an aggregate); since the relationships are between things between aggregates in different bounded contexts, this is probably going to be its own bounded context.

The aggregate is basically just holding references (by ID, not references in the programming language sense) to the roots of the related aggregates (if the relationship is free-form in terms of what can be related, these IDs would also encode the type of aggregate).

It bears noting that as we're crossing bounded contexts (which generally could conceivably start operating at network distance from each other), it's reasonably likely that some level of eventual consistency will come into play: I'd advise against trying to enforce strong foreign key-style constraints on the relationships unless you're absolutely sure that you'll never run bounded contexts at network distance from each other (and make it clear that this relationship bounded context will prevent that from being done).

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful.  I was thinking of having the user enter a note to address why the objects are related, so that could be an entity of the new relationship aggregate.  Further, would it be possible to use the same concept to relate an entity within an aggregate to another resource aggregate using their IDs?  e.g., relate a 'page' entity (e.g., P. 6) within a 'book' aggregate to a 'Map_Location' aggregate or an  'Artwork' aggregate.

Comment: There's no reason you couldn't do that.

Comment: Thanks again Levi, very helpful